# Compiling C code with MSVS2012 and two ";;"s

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

Code:

```
char* to_return = NULL;;
char* final_encoding = NULL;
```

Fails to compile.

Error: `error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'`

Same behaviour for:

```
int something = 0;;
```

(I just wanted to be sure that the NULL macro is not messing things up)

Code:

```
char* to_return = NULL;
char* final_encoding = NULL;
```

Succeeds.

Compiled as C not C++... with Visual Studio 2012. Why???

Edit:

The following code triggers this erroneous behaviour:

```
void test_fun()
{
    ;
    int a = 0;
    if(a == 1)
    {
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe they implemented it that way to prevent accidental `if( ... );`, `while(...);`, etc.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue.  Have you included `<stddef.h>` or some other header that defines `NULL`?  What is the complete source file that demonstrates this issue?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Yes, `stddef.h` is included

Comment: With regards to @ThoAppelsin's answer, what if you put the `;;` at the end of your declarations? If that compiles, then he is correct.

Comment: Even with the latest revision, I would argue that my guess could be the reason. I wish that @clcto s request was tested.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin I have tested clcto's request, the code compiles ...

Comment: Stop trying to use VS as a C compiler.  It isn't one.  You might as well use a c++ compiler on your python sources.  If you want to use visual studio, write c++.  If you want to write c, use a c compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't take my word on this, but it likely is due to having a statement before a variable declaration inside a code block; where the statement is `;`, the empty statement, and the varaible is `char* final_encoding`.

My Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 doesn't complain, and as far as I know VS 2012 doesn't support `C99` *not even* as much as VS 2013 does, although 2013 also doesn't fully comply either.

Comment: I'm sure this is it.  When compiling code as C in VS, you _still_ need variable declarations before anything, including empty statements.

Comment: There are no statements before the variable declarations in the code. It's C code, written as "old" C code :(

Comment: @fritzone Unfortunately, I don't know what an *old C code* is... As far as I can tell, `;` alone is a statement. You can clarify whether this really is the reason or not, by putting singe semicolons `;` after each declaration, except for the last declaration, where you shall put double semicolons `;;`, or triple `;;;` whatever.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin old C code, pretty bad wording from me. so: code written conforming with the C standard C90. And see the edit... So as it seems `;` is treated as a statement.

Comment: Confirming the issue under VS 2012. This is most likely the answer.

Comment: You can also check that `;` is a statement and not a declaration, by reading the grammar specification in the C standard :)

Answer (score 0):

```
char* to_return = NULL;;
char* final_encoding = NULL;
```

Whether this is legal depends on where it appears (inside or outside a function definition) and on the version of the language that your compiler supports.

A lone semicolon is a *null statement*. I don't think there are any cases where a null statement is necessary, but it can improve clarity, as in:

```
while (*foo++ = *bar++)
    ;
```

If the above declarations appear at file scope, outside any function definition, then the extra semicolon is a syntax error; there is no such thing as an empty declaration, and statements are not allowed at file scope.

If they appear at block scope, somewhere between the `{` and `}` of a function definition, then they're valid *if* your compiler supports C99 or later.  If your compiler only supports C90 (as I believe Microsoft's compiler does), it's a syntax error. (C++ has always permitted mixed declarations and statements.)

On the other hand, some compilers may permit a stray semicolon at block scope as a language extension. gcc does so by default; with the `-pedantic` option, it issues a warning.

In C99, you have a declaration, followed by an empty statement, followed by another declaration, which is perfectly legal at block scope.

In C90, declarations may not follow statements within the same scope, so again it's a syntax error.

In any case, the solution is easy: delete the extra semicolon.